# Format Grid nicely

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grid, jsx

I'm trying to display data in an "easy to the eye" way, but having a hard time constructing it correctly.

I want to format the page as follow: 1st Grid contains 3 text fields, one below the other with appropriate title above them all. 2nd Grid is the same with 3 other fields , and the 3rd Grid contains 7 text field, which I wanna display -> 3 in the first column, 2 in the second and 2 and the last one, all under the same title.

If I put all the 7 last fields under the same grid, they all appear in the same column. Right now it almost works, but only the 3 first textfields are margined correctly below the title, and the other 4 appears on a different margin .

This is my code:(if someone has an idea of improving the display, I'm more than open to hear about it)

```
    <Grid container spacing={24}>
      <Grid item sm={3}> // First grid - contains 3 text fields
        <Typography variant="subheading" gutterBottom color="primary" >
          {labels.brokerGeneralDetails}
        </Typography>
        <Grid item sm={10}>
          <TextField
            ...
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item sm={2}>
          <TextField
            ...
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item sm={2}>
          <TextField
            ...
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item sm={1}>  // Second grid - contains 3 text fields
        <Typography variant="subheading" gutterBottom color="primary">
          {labels.brokerAccountDetails}
        </Typography>
        <Grid item sm={6}>
          <TextField
           ...
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item sm={3}>
          <TextField
            ...
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item sm={2}>
          <TextField
            ...
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item sm={3}>  // Third grid - Should contain 7 text fields in 3 columns
        <Typography variant="subheading" gutterBottom color="primary">
          {labels.brokerOtherDetails}
        </Typography>
        <Grid >
          <TextField
            ...
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item sm={2}>
          <TextField
            ...
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item sm={1}>
          <TextField
            ...
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item sm={1}> // Should be the second column
        <Grid>
          <TextField
            ...
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid >
          <TextField
           ...
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item sm={1}> // Should be the third column
        <Grid>
          <TextField
          ...
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
          <TextField
           ...
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

I want it to be displayed as follow :

```
                    Title3          Title2       Title1
       Txt6   Txt4   Txt1          Txt1         Txt1
       Txt7   Txt5   Txt2          Txt2         Txt2
                     Txt3          Txt3         Txt3
```

Right now it is :

```
       Txt6   Txt4  Title3          Title2       Title1
       Txt7   Txt5   Txt1          Txt1         Txt1
                     Txt2          Txt2         Txt2
                     Txt3          Txt3         Txt3
```

Comment: can you attach the design here ?

Comment: A picture of the current display? @SakhiMansoor

Comment: No I mean the desired output

Comment: @SakhiMansoor Updated

Comment: I added a answer below. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to build a grid based on what you want but I would do it like so:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Column="2" Content="Title3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="36"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="3" Content="Title2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="36"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="4" Content="Title1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="36"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Content="Txt6" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="36"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Content="Txt4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="36"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Content="Txt1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="36"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Content="Txt1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="36"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" Content="Txt1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="36"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Content="Txt7" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="36"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Content="Txt5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="36"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Content="Txt2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="36"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" Content="Txt2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="36"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2" Content="Txt2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="36"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Content="Txt3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="36"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" Content="Txt3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="36"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="3" Content="Txt3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="36"/>
</Grid>
```

Output looks like this: https://gyazo.com/b6768ab550ddac6685549c35e38b34e9

You can also use `Grid.ColumnSpan` to span multiple columns of your grid, if you want to center a title above all 5 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Use alignItems in your Grid: `alignItems="center"`

```
<Grid container spacing={24} alignItems="center">
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending some time I think I did this:
here is the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/ll507vypy7

code :

```
const styles = theme => ({
root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  textField: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit,
    marginRight: theme.spacing.unit,
    width: 50
  }
});

class TextFields extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Grid container>
          <Grid item container xs={4}>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <Typography variant="subheading" gutterBottom color="primary">
                Grid1
              </Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField className={classes.textField} />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField className={classes.textField} />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField className={classes.textField} />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item container xs={4}>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <Typography variant="subheading" gutterBottom color="primary">
                Grid2
              </Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField className={classes.textField} />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField className={classes.textField} />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField className={classes.textField} />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <Grid container item xs={4}>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <Typography variant="subheading" gutterBottom color="primary">
                Grid3
              </Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid container item xs={12}>
              <Grid item xs={4}>
                <TextField className={classes.textField} />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={4}>
                <TextField className={classes.textField} />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={4}>
                <TextField className={classes.textField} />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid container item xs={12}>
              <Grid item xs={4}>
                <TextField className={classes.textField} />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={4}>
                <TextField className={classes.textField} />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid container item xs={12}>
              <Grid item xs={4}>
                <TextField className={classes.textField} />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={4}>
                <TextField className={classes.textField} />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

PS it's **MATERIAL-UI**